# How to batch edit dbf files with powershell?

Tags: powershell, dbf, dbase

How to batch edit dbf files with powershell?

Comment: Your tag says "dbf", but your title and body text say "dbg" - typo?

Comment: If it is possible, it would be through ADO. Did you try searching for that topic?

Comment: dbf can represents a few different types of database files. Do you know which database generated these files? Can you find an ODBC driver that can connect to these files?

Comment: The dbf i using for is GIS ( geographic information system ) related. I'm trying to edit CDB generated database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still writing a dBase for the (inter)net usage.
I don't know, if I use *.dbf of MySQL, yet.
But the project goal is to present a customer web developer platform
in graphical manner.
So, you have windows, buttons, and not only text fields.
At the moment, I work on the graphical framework in PHP (server), and JavaScript (user client side).
A second goal is, to provide all what you need to successfully create rapid
database products without having doubts about the deployment (missing files, updates ...)
The project is still internal usage. But coming soon...
I ask/answer here to you, with the self question, did you interesting in such
a product?